# Line with .loc is sometimes returning zeros but sometimes works OK

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for the first occurrence of a value in the 'Call' column of a DataFrame dependant on the value in the 'Loop' column. The code works properly for the first 19 rows (up to index 18) and then starts returning zeros. The program is very complex and is written in a serial manner with very few functions in order to be able to keep track of what is happening.  It converts g-code into svg. I need a simple fix for this line (which is repeated with minor variations in the program) and not to re-write the whole thing.

I have checked that the Active_Loop data is the correct value (1) and an integer before it is changed to a string in the offending line. I have checked that the DataFrame has the correct values entered. The line worked for 19 iterations before falling over so there does not appear to be any syntax errors.

The code in question is: -

```
Current_Call = Loop_Data_Frame.loc[Loop_Data_Frame["Loop"].str.contains(str(Active_Loop), na=False), "Call"].values[1]
```

The DataFrame is: -

```
Loop data frame Line 1177 - Loop_Data_Frame:
    Loop  Call  Line                                           Text
0     0     0     0                          2660 G83 X-46 Y+0 Z+0
1     0     0     0                          2661 G83 X-46 Y+0 Z+0
2    60     0     1           27 G01 G90 X+63.45 Y-18.45 F9998 M13
3    60     0     2  28 G83 P01 -2 P02 -10.1 P03 -10 P04 0 P05 571
4    60     0     3                                         29 G79
5    60     0     4                        30 G56 G91 X+46 Y+0 Z+0
6    60     0     5                                      31 G98 L0
7    61     0     1                          42 G01 G91 Z-3.5 F499
8    61     0     2                             43 G01 G90 X+136.5
9    61     0     3                                     44 G98 L62
10   62     0     1                              45 G01 G90 Y-60.5
11   62     0     2                                46 G01 G91 X-46
12   62     0     3                               47 G01 G90 Y+0.5
13   62     0     4                                      48 G98 L0
14   62     0     1                                 50 G01 G90 X-7
15   62     0     2                                      51 G98 L0
16   63     0     1                 57 G01 G90 X+63.45 Y-18.45 M13
17   63     0     2                            58 G01 G90 Z-1 F499
18   63     0     3                                      59 G98 L1
19    1     0     1                          60 G07 G91 Z-4.9 F250
20    1     0     2                        61 G07 G91 Z+10.3 F9998
21    1     0     3                        62 G07 G91 Z-10.3 F1000
22    1     0     4                        63 G01 G90 Y-41.55 F499
23    1     0     5                             64 G01 G90 X+71.55
24    1     0     6                             65 G01 G90 Y-18.45
25    1     0     7                             66 G01 G90 X+63.45
26    1     0     8                                      67 G98 L0
```

Comment: Can you show what the value of `Current_Call` is and what you expected it to be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong version of the DataFrame. I have asked for an edit but it seems to take a while. The values in the call column from index 19 to 26 should be 1. Therefore it should return a 1 when  Loop == 1 but is returning a 0. The code works on previous rows and has returned at least a 1 and a 2 maybe more.

Comment: Having proved that the code sometimes works and sometimes does not. I decided to use a different method and split the operation into the two following lines.   Call_Index = Loop_Data_Frame.index[Loop_Data_Frame['Loop'] == str(Active_Loop)].values[0] and Current_Call = Loop_Data_Frame['Call'].loc[Loop_Data_Frame.index[Call_Index]] These work every time!

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code with the dataframe values you provided and `Active_Loop = 1` I get the expected answer `'0'`.

What were you expecting it to be?

Note that `Loop_Data_Frame.loc[Loop_Data_Frame["Loop"].str.contains(str(Active_Loop), na=False), "Call"].values` returns the following  array:

```
array(['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], dtype=object)
```

These are the values of the column 'Call' which correspond to the rows in column 'Loop' which contain `'1'`.

Therefore, `Current_Call` contains `'0'` which is the *second* value in the above array.

Tip: When debugging a compound statement like this one, it's best to break it down into parts and inspect each part to make sure it makes sense.